# BackKey button function in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

this is my problem. Everytime i hit the backbutton on any android device, the application automatically closes. Is there any way i could make the back button of the device load the previous activity?

Here are the codes

```
package com.phonegap.mobilemone;
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class KeyBoard {

        private WebView mAppView;
        private DroidGap mGap;

        public KeyBoard(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
        {
            mAppView = view;
            mGap = gap;
        }

        public void showKeyBoard() {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)     mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
            mgr.showSoftInput(mAppView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            
            ((InputMethodManager)     mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(mAppView, 0); 

        }
        
        public void hideKeyBoard() {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)     mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAppView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, when you press `back button` you goes to previous `Activity`, But when developing `PhoneGap` app, you are working on single `Activity` (this is the reason when you press `back` button, application gets close). You need to implement your own listener which will listen `back` key press.

***How to create Android Back Button handler:***

*phonegap 0.9.5 and later:*

// This is your app's init method. Here's an example of how to use it

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDR, false);
} 
function onDR(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
    //boot your app...
}
function backKeyDown() { 
    // do something here if you wish
    // alert('go back!');
}
```

*phonegap 0.9.4 and earlier:*

// This is your app's init method. Here's an example of how to use it

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDR, false);
}
function onDR(){
    BackButton.override(); 
    document.addEventListener("backKeyDown", backKeyDown, true);
    //boot your app...
}
function backKeyDown() { 
    // do something here if you wish
    // alert('go back!');
}
```

Here are References :

[Back button handler](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

[CATCHING ANDROID’S BACK BUTTON IN PHONEGAP](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/catching-androids-back-button-in-phonegap/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this...Specify ur Target Activity class name using intent.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent BackpressedIntent = new Intent();
    BackpressedIntent .setClass(getApplicationContext(),TargetActivity.class);
    startActivity(BackpressedIntent );
    finish();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by specify my target activity class name? sorry im newbie., but thank you.